# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price') - Next.js 14.0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I don't know why it's not working in Next.js, but it still works normally in another templates.

```
let subTotal = 0

    if (selectedProducts?.length) {
        for (let id of selectedProducts) {
            const price = products.find(product => product.id === id).price
            subTotal += price
        }
    }
```

Here my GitHub code: [e-commerce](https://github.com/truonganhvu205/e-commerce)

I've tried everything that i know, please i need help, tysm.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `products.find(product => product.id === id)` isn't returning an object in at least one iteration of the loop. Maybe include a little defensive coding to ensure that price is available.

```
for (let id of selectedProducts) {

  // Get the object first
  const product = products.find(product => product.id === id);

  // If the product exists AND the price exists on the object
  // add it to the subtotal
  if (product?.price) subTotal += product.price;
}
```

For example:

```js
const products = [
  { id: 1, name: 'potato', price: 2 },
  { id: 2, name: 'fish', price: 12 },
  { id: 3, name: 'gammon', price: 22 },
  { id: 4, name: 'radish', price: 1 }
];

const selectedProducts = [1, 3, 6];

let subtotal = 0;

for (const id of selectedProducts) {
  const product = products.find(product => product.id === id);
  if (product?.price) subtotal += product.price;
}

console.log(subtotal);
```

Additional documentation

- [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

Inside `useEffect` set the loading state inside `then` block to make sure you  set the loading state right after async data fetching

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products", {
      next: {
        revalidate: 60,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setProducts(json);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    // ---- NOT HERE -----
    // setLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

then calculate the subTotal after `loading==false`

```
 let subTotal = 0;
  if (!loading && selectedProducts?.length) {
    for (let id of selectedProducts) {
      const price = products.find((product) => product.id === id).price;
      subTotal += price;
    }
  }
```